# Why I am not receving response ?( Details not updating in Laravel Vue js Web Sockets)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket

(PHP ^7.2.5 and laravel ^7.24 , beyondcode laravel:^1.12pusher/pusher-php-server 5.0.3     Library for interacting with the Pusher REST API
)

> Env File
> This is my env file. Id and Key values are real and I have used it in bootstrap.js file
>
> ```html
> PUSHER_APP_ID=myappid
> PUSHER_APP_KEY=myappkey
> PUSHER_APP_SECRET=myappsecret
> PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
> ```
>
> After following the tutorial from this link [https://medium.com/@aschmelyun/adding-real-time-updates-to-your-laravel-and-vue-apps-with-laravel-websockets-a1d9a69f7c12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcFTl.png)
> Event File

```html
class OrderEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels, OtherTrait;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $orders;
    public $orderRepo;
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->orders = 'Hello World';
        //return response()->json(ResponseHelper::GenerateResponse(200, '', ['order' => $order]), 200);
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('orders');
    }    
}
```

> Bootstrap.js File

```html
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'myappkey',
    cluster: 'mt1',
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: false,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
});
```

Component File

```html
 created() {
    window.Echo.channel("orders").listen("OrderEvent", (e) => {
      debugger;
      console.log(e.orders);
      //this.setEchotoWork(e.orders);
    });
    this.fetchData();
  },
```

[image: I am not able to understand this]

[image]

Comment: I change BROADCAST_DRIVER=log to BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher in env file. But getting pusher array_merge error. any help will be apreciated. (PHP ^7.2.5 and laravel ^7.24)Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting error related to array_merge

check pusher/pusher-php-server version

using cmd
composer show

if it is not 4.1 run cmd
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server ^4.1